# working with strongly typed data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I'm using asp.net with Razor
I have a controller that returns  return View(db.sales.ToList());

my model is

```
   public class sales
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string month { get; set; }
    public int sale {get;set;}
}
```

My view gets

```
@model IEnumerable<salesmonths.Models.sales>
```

i'm creating  a chart using Javascript 
how to extract the months into a string table
and the sales into an int table

and this is the chart script

```
<script>

    var barChartData = {
        labels : ["January"],/// i want to place the month table here
        datasets : [

            {
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100] /// and the sale table here
            }
        ]

    }

var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);

</script>
```

Comment: turn the model into json and give the json to js.

Comment: @user3353484 I updated my answer to match with the edit you made to your question. That code should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make an ajax call once you page finishes loading to your controller action method to get the data in **JSON** format and use that to build the chart. Most chart libraries accept JSON format data as input to draw the chart.

```
$(function(){

  $.getJSON("@Url.Action("Sales","Home")",function(response){
    //JSON data is in "response" variable now.
  });

});
```

Assuming your Action method returns JSON representation when the call is from an ajax request. You may use the `Request.IsAjaxRequest` method to determine whether the request is coming from an ajax request or a normal http request.

```
public ActionResult Sales()
{
   var saleListVM=new List<salesmonths.Models.Sales>();
   // to do :Load data to the list
   if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
   {
      return Json(saleListVM,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
   }
   //not an ajax request- let's return the view model the normal view
   return View(saleListVM);
}
```

So this action method will return a JSON representation of your data like below one when being called with an ajax request.

```
[
    {     "ID": 0, "month": "Jan", "sale": 134   },
    {     "ID": 0, "month": "FEb", "sale": 534   }
]
```

Now in your getJSON method's call back, you may loop through the items in the array and set that to the "options" of the chart.
    
    $(function () {

```
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("Sales","Home")", function (response) {
        var salesLabels = [];
        var salesData = [];

        //Let's loop through the items in array and add to our temp array

        $.each(response, function (index, item) {
            salesLabels.push(item.month);
            salesData.push(item.sale);
        });

        var barChartData = {
                labels: salesLabels,
                datasets: [
                            {
                                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                data: salesData
                            }
                        ]
                    };

       var myLine=new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"))
                                                         .Bar(barChartData);


    });

});
</script>
```